# Making sure I'm not doing something wrong

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm solving a matrix equation: $$2(A-B+X) = 3(X-A)$$

Where $A = \left( \begin{matrix} 1&2 \\ 3&4 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $B = \left( \begin{matrix} -1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{matrix} \right) $

So far I've done: $$2(A-B+x) = 3(X - A)$$ $$\Rightarrow 2 \left( \begin{matrix} 1&2 \\ 3&4 \end{matrix} - \begin{matrix} -1&0 \\ 1&1 \end{matrix} + X \right) = 3 \left( X - \begin{matrix} 1&2 \\ 3&4 \end{matrix} \right)$$

$$ \Rightarrow 2 \left( \begin{matrix} 2&2 \\ 2&3 \end{matrix} + X \right) = 3X - \begin{matrix} 3&6 \\ 9&12 \end{matrix}$$
$$\Rightarrow \begin{matrix} 4&4 \\ 4&6 \end{matrix} + 2X = 3X - \begin{matrix} 3&6 \\ 9&12 \end{matrix}$$

But I'm not sure if I can put it on this form, asssuming the 2 matrices form the matrix $C$ when added:

$$C + 2X = 3X$$

Because I remember something about watching out for positioning when subtracting two matrices..

Some help needed with the next step.

Comment: Subtraction of matrices (as long as they are of the same size) follows the same rules as subtraction of numbers.  I think perhaps you are getting mixed up with *multiplication* of matrices, where order is important: $AB$ is not always equal to $BA$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be more clear if you don't write out the elements until necessary.

$$2(A-B+X) = 3(X-A) \\
2A-2B+2X = 3X-3A \\
5A-2B = X$$

Matrices add and subtract normally; that is, $A+A = 2A, 10Q-8Q = 2Q, 3X-2X = X,$ etc.

Comment: Thank you. is this generally the best way to go about these?

Comment: For addition and subtraction, it is the only way to go about it.